# Failed to read schema document Schema Cloudfoundry

Tags: java, spring, maven, cloud-foundry, appfog

I'm developing an app with Java and Spring and I'm trying to upload it to AppFog.

The application is working properly and it's working in AppFog, but in Eclipse I'm getting a very annoying error in my `applicationContext.xml` file.

According to the documentation in AppFog I have to set it up like this: [Spring - AppFog Documentation](https://docs.appfog.com/languages/java/spring)

**Snippet of my applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd 
        http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring 
        http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring.xsd">

<cloud:data-source id="dataSource">
```

In the tag `cloud:data source` I'm getting the error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring.xsd', 
 because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cloud:data-source'.
```

I've tried with `http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring-0.8.xsd` and different versions but I'm always getting the same error.

I have included in my pom the next library too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudfoundry-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Some ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your app is working locally and on AppFog, but as you say the issue is a validation error in Eclipse. Are you using the Spring Tool Suite plugin? What should actually happen here is that the schema should be found within the Spring Jar file (the source is on Github https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java/blob/master/cloudfoundry-runtime/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.schemas) - I guess there should be a way of telling Eclipse to resolve it there, and I suspect that STS would actually know how to resolve it.